# setting extra paths in sublime text 3 error expected comma or closing bracket

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext3, anaconda, sublimetext, sublime-anaconda

I'm trying to add an extra path to sublime in anaconda settings, but i get this error, what I'm doing wrong with the settings ??

maybe I'm missing a coma but i don't understand this kind of formatting .. any idea?

```
{

    "auto_formatting": false,
    "autoformat_ignore":
    [
        "E309",
        "E501"

    ],
    "pep8_ignore":
    [
        "E309",
        "E501",
        "E302",
        "E265",
        "E305",
        "E702",
        "E231",
        "E221",
        "E303"
    ],
    "pyflakes_explicit_ignore":
    [
        "UnusedImport"
    ],
    "anaconda_linter_underlines": false,
    "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none",
    "display_signatures": false,
    "disable_anaconda_completion": false


    ],
    "extra_paths":
    [
        "C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/Python/Lib/site-packages"
    ],

}
```

Comment: You have an extra unneeded `],` before `extra_paths`. The file format is JSON, so throwing it through jsonlint.com will tell you where the error is as well.

Answer (score 1):

The above given sublime text config is in JSON format.

The issue with the config is that it had extra **]** and trailing **,**

Below is the syntax corrected config file.

```
{  
  "auto_formatting":false,
   "autoformat_ignore":[  
      "E309",
      "E501"
   ],
   "pep8_ignore":[  
      "E309",
      "E501",
      "E302",
      "E265",
      "E305",
      "E702",
      "E231",
      "E221",
      "E303"
   ],
   "pyflakes_explicit_ignore":[  
      "UnusedImport"
   ],
   "anaconda_linter_underlines":false,
   "anaconda_linter_mark_style":"none",
   "display_signatures":false,
   "disable_anaconda_completion":false,
   "extra_paths":[  
      "C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/Python/Lib/site-packages"
   ]
}
```